# Jupyter : change output cell size

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I'm using Jupyter on vscode and every time, since the last update, I see the whole output window which is sometimes annoying when it's very big. I would like to reduce it and just be able to scroll through it. I tried to modifiy the 'Max output size' setting but it didn't change anything for me. Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer on the VS Code notebook team. Currently, we are transitioning over to a new UI. This setting is just something that got lost in that transition from the old UI. I've filed a bug here that you can track for adding this support back into the new UI.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6506

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code in **setting.json** file.

```
"notebook.outputFontSize": 9,
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).