# VS Code and Jupyter Notebook - how to open large output in text editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm running jupyter notebooks in VSCode and have a return of a very large json - too large to see it all in the jupyter notebook.

When I prettyprint the json in VSCode, it shows some of the data, then:
"show more (open the raw output data in a text editor) . . . "

When I click on that, VSCode pops up a msg, "The window is not responding".

How do I make this link work and open that json in Notepad++, which is installed?

Alternatively, how can I dump this json to text file so I can view in a text editor?

Comment: Figured out how to write to file. Is there a way to incorporate the prettyprint formatting in the output that is written to file? `import json with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:       output_file.write(json.dumps(output_data))`

Answer (score 14):

Once notebooks were natively supported by VSCode, the setting changed to `notebook.output.textLineLimit`.

Comment: this doens't work for me

Answer (score 4):

You can try to set the 'Max Output Size', which is the setting of the jupyter extension,  and check if it works.
[image]

If the 'Max Output Size' can't work, use [logs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) or files to keep your output is wise.

Comment: I set this ("notebook.output.textLineLimit") to 0, which indicates that the output is unlimited. And it worked

Comment: anyway I cannot find this option in my vscode

Answer (score 1):

On VSCode version 1.77.3 is
**Notebook > Output: Text Line Limit**

[image]