# Enlarging inline plots in the VSCode Jupyter notebook extension

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using Visual Studio Code with the Jupyter notebook extension. Using matplotlib with the inline backend (via the `%matplotlib inline` magic), plots tend to be small. This does not seem to be the case with the `%matplotlib widget` backend.

Is there a way to enlarge it?

Comment: See [my comment to the current only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77881743/enlarging-inline-plots-in-the-vscode-jupyter-notebook-extension#comment137302048_77881750) detailing that this topic seems already well covered on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to explicitly pass a dpi parameter during figure creation, for example:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=300)
```

Comment: More is covered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55051471/8508004) to the post entitled 'How to make inline plots in Jupyter Notebook larger?'. That is already marked as a DUPLICATE post. And I note there's also [this post entitled 'How to change size of VS Code jupyter notebook graphs?'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67837572/8508004) indicating this is already well covered on StackOverflow.